# How many Bitcoin addresses can I generate through Coinbase API?

Tags: api, currency, bitcoin, cryptoapi, coinbase-api

I use Coinbase [API](https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#create-address) to generate Bitcoin addresses.

What are the limits of this API?

How many Bitcoin addresses can I generate?

Answer (score 1):

The API says that:

> The Coinbase API is rate limited to prevent abuse that would degrade our ability to maintain consistent API performance for all users. By default, each API key or app is rate limited at 10,000 requests per hour. If your requests are being rate limited, HTTP response code 429 will be returned with an rate_limit_exceeded error.

So I would reason to assume you can generate 10,000 BTC addresses per hour. Of course there might be somewhere else it has been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

API docs say it is unlimited for each account.

> Address resource represents a bitcoin, bitcoin cash, litecoin or ethereum address for an account. Account can have unlimited amount of addresses and they should be used only once.

This text is taken from the official api docs (link down below) on date 04-02-2020
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#addresses